# .NET MAUI: Is there a way to resize Label's text dynamically?

Tags: .net, xaml, maui

I have been using WPF for quite a while, where Viewbox element is being used to make app change Label's FontSize property, along with window's dimensions. In MAUI there is no Viewbox anymore. As far as I'm concerned, text can still be resized dynamically from codebehind, but it's inconvenient for me. Is there a possibility to make GUI's element text resize dynamically, without involving functional side of an app?

Comment: No, this is not possible because this concept does not exist in mobile development, you do have the option to let your user decide what the font size of the application should be and you can scale the rest of your fonts based on that

Comment: There is no way can do this in the maui. You can try to bind the fontsize property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an extremely useful plugin for Maui [OnScreenSizeMarkup](https://github.com/carolzbnbr/OnScreenSizeMarkup.Maui) which is very customisable and has a very good demo project inside showing how to use it for scaling across sizes.